# How to delete data from multiple tables in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite database to store data. I have three tables: Invoice, InvRow, Invdetails.

Relationsip between the tables are:

```
Invoice.Id = InvRow.InvId
InvRow.Id = Invdetails.RowId
```

I need to delete related entries from three tables using a single query. How can I do that?
Any help?

Answer (score 8):

SQLite prior to version 3.6.19 (2009 Oct 14) does not support foreign key constraints, but you can [use triggers to maintain relational integrity](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ForeignKeyTriggers).

[Starting with 3.6.19](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_6_19.html), however, SQLite supports proper [foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) with `ON [UPDATE|DELETE] CASCADE` clauses, that will do what you want.

Comment: Hi Checkers, how is the delete performance compared with manual delete? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Alex B provides a good answer but it didn't work for me. too much work right now.

Unfortunately I had to do the delete in two statements, but it worked out just fine. I have two tables, movies and movie_providers, movie_providers is a join table that tells which provider is showing my movie.

I wanted:
`DELETE FROM movies, movie_pproviders WHERE movie.id = movie_providers.movie_id AND [my constraint]`

but had to do 2 steps

```
DELETE FROM movies WHERE [my constraint]
DELETE FROM movie_providers where movie_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM movies)
```

This assumes i had consistency between movies and movie_providers before. If not, I just created consistency.